# How can I check for location updates within a scaffold of a body of GoogleMap in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, geolocation, location

I want to be able to monitor for location updates within the GoogleMap body so when the user approaches a certain point on the map the if statement in checkFirstClue() is called and an alert dialog pops up. However checkFirstClue() is not being except once. How can I make it that checkFirstClue() is constantly being called.
Thanks

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
  late GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;
  Position? currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  final double dcheck = 0.00014128694207108202;

  void locatePosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLngPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        new CameraPosition(target: latLngPosition, zoom: 14);
    newGoogleMapController
        .moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
  }

  checkpermission_location() async {
    var locationStatus = await Permission.location.status;
    print(locationStatus);

    if (!locationStatus.isGranted) {
      print("gr");
      await Permission.location.request();
    }

    if (!locationStatus.isDenied) {
      print('de');
      await Permission.location.request();
      locatePosition();
    }
  }

  void updatePosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLngPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
  }

  void checkFirstClue() {
    updatePosition();
    double distance = methods.distance(
        mapVar.firstClue.position.latitude,
        mapVar.firstClue.position.longitude,
        currentPosition?.latitude,
        currentPosition?.longitude);
    log("distance: $distance");
    if (distance < dcheck) {
      mapVar.showAlertDialog(context);
    }
  }

  //Initial camera position when maps first load
  static const _initalCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(52.2053, 0.1218),
    zoom: 11.5,
  );

  //Google map widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Checks if mapAcess is true
    if (variables.mapAccess) {
      checkFirstClue();
      return Scaffold(
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            controller.setMapStyle(mapVar.mapStyle);
            checkpermission_location();
            _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
            newGoogleMapController = controller;
            locatePosition();
          },
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          markers: {
            //Markers located in the variables.dart file
            mapVar.firstClue,
            mapVar.secondClue,
            mapVar.thirdClue
          },
          initialCameraPosition: _initalCameraPosition,
        ),
      );
    }
    //Refuses access if 10 Digit key is not provided
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Text('You do not have access to the map, please login')));
  }
}
```

EDIT ANSWER:
Used location plugin to listen for updates when the location is changed.

```
 var location = new Location();

  checkpermission_location() async {
    var locationStatus = await Permission.location.status;
    print(locationStatus);

    if (!locationStatus.isGranted) {
      print("gr");
      await Permission.location.request();
    }

    if (!locationStatus.isDenied) {
      print('de');
      await Permission.location.request();
      location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
        var lat = currentLocation.latitude;
        var long = currentLocation.longitude;
        checkFirstClue(lat, long);
      });
    }
```

Comment: I can see that you are already using `Geolocator` that will allow you to get the current location of the device. However, you are only moving the map to the current location `onMapCreated`. Are you trying to show the current location every minute?

Comment: @jabamataro Yes I am trying to show/get the current location as often as possible because I want to show an alert dialog when a user reaches a certain destination(marker). Thanks for your reply!